# Python2.7 - Passing argument to command line to filter CSV according to parameter

Tags: python, csv, argparse

I don't have code yet for this because I am not sure how to tackle.
Using the `tfidfVectorizer` in the `sci-kit` in `python`, I have calculated the `tfidf` score for terms used in Movie Reviews.

I output my results into a `CSV` file with 4 columns that contain

```
Col1 = indDocID 
Col2 = Word 
Col3 = MovieID 
Col4 = Score
```

I would like to pass a command line argument that would parse the CSV file and print only those results that correspond to `MovieID`.

In that way, directly from the command line, I would be able to call the results that I am interested in as files `$python tfidf.py -i uniqMovieID`

I have been reading up on all of the literature regarding passing a command line argument and have been experimenting with my code, but they don't seem to address the problem that I have of filtering the information that contains the same `MovieID` that I indicate directly in the command line.

An example of the data in the `CSV` file is

```
indDocID,Word,MovieID,Score
1,love,4583B,.09
2,good,4583B,.37
3,funny,4583B,.64
4,love,34623C,.34
5,hate,34623C,.57
```

My goal is to run the script with the following command `python tfidf.py -i 4583B` so that the result is:

```
indDocID,Word,MovieID,Score
1,love,4583B,.09
2,good,4583B,.37
3,funny,4583B,.64
```

I have been looking [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html) and I have tried certain examples such as

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-i", "--idMovie", dest="arg",
                  help="insertMovieIds", metavar="variable")
```

as well as this:

```
def main(argv):
   movieIds = ''

   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:",["movieid="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <movieID>'
      sys.exit(1)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'tfidf.py -i <movieIds>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--id"):
         movieIds = arg

   print 'MovieID is:', movieIds



if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Yet I am not sure how to successfuly integrate them into my code so that it is associated to a specific row in my `CSV` to arrive at the above desired result.

Comment: Did you try using pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/  ?

Comment: We have been trying to avoid using the inevitable database by appending to a CSV to keep updating our list. Pandas will be the next step though @DainDwarf

Comment: `optparse` and `sys.argv` are just ways of getting the number/string into your program.  Using that to filter the `csv` data is a distinct problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `csv.DictReader` pulling any rows that match the unique `MovieID` passed in to your script:

```
import csv
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-i", "--idMovie", dest="arg",
                  help="insertMovieIds", metavar="variable")
opt, args = parser.parse_args()
un_id = opt.arg
with open("out.txt") as f:
    names = next(f).rstrip().split(",")
    r = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=names)
    print(",".join(names))
    for d in r:
        if un_id == d["MovieID"]:
            print(",".join([d[n] for n in names]))
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py -i 4583B 
indDocID,Word,MovieID,Score
1,love,4583B,.09
2,good,4583B,.37
3,funny,4583B,.64
```

You need to add your error checking back in etc.. if you want to reuse the code for different cols just put the logic a function, you also probably only want to print the header if you find a match and if no match is found report that to the user:

```
def find_by_val(col, k, fle, delim=","):
    with open(fle) as f:
        names = next(f).rstrip().split(delim)
        if col not in names:
            print("Column does not exist.")
            return
        r, found = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=names), False
        for d in r:
            if un_id == d[col]:
                if not found:
                    print(",".join(names))
                    print(",".join([d[n] for n in names]))
                    found = True
                else:
                    print(",".join([d[n] for n in names]))
        if not found:
            print("No matching value for {} found".format(k))
```

Output:

```
padraic@lab:~$ python test.py -i 4583B 
indDocID,Word,MovieID,Score
1,love,4583B,.09
2,good,4583B,.37
3,funny,4583B,.64
padraic@lab:~$ python test.py -i foo
No matching value for foo found
```

If you store the output in lists, you could write it a little more succinctly:

```
def find_by_val(col, k, fle, delim=","):
    with open(fle) as f:
        names = next(f).rstrip().split(delim)
        if col not in names:
            print("Column does not exist.")
            return
        r, found = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=names), False
        output = [",".join(d[n] for n in names) for d in r if d[col] == k ]
        if not output:
            print("No matching value for {} found".format(k))
        else:
            print(",".join(names))
            print("\n".join(output))
```

You should also probably take the column name as an argument and take multiple values to look for if you want a more general approach.

Comment: Excellent. Worked absolutely like a charm. The generality of it is useful too in case I need to parse by a different variable in the future. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match rows only against MoveID using additional argument -i may be unnecessary (additional argument can be helpful if you need to specify, which column we use to match against). You can test the code below with `python tfidf.py 4583B`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, csv

def search(db, mid):
    # open csv file
    with open(db, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for r in reader:
            # print line if MovieID matches
            if r[2] == mid:
                print(','.join(r))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse arguments    
    db, mid = sys.argv[1:]
    search(db, mid)
```

Comment: This is not a very general approach, you would have to know the column index